# Black triangles/weird texture on character

Tags: uv, shaders

It only appears on this character, and it can't be the light because even if I shine a spot light on it, although its not black, the outlines are still there. I noticed it wasn't affecting a character far away so I stole his head and when side by side, its being affected by it too. I disabled sky dome and particle system plane above him but it didn't help. No HDR. There is no texture, his skin is just pure white via the color in the BSDF. No nodes besides the default. It ONLY shows in render view. Viewport doesn't have this issue. Trying to render in cycles. Ideas? [image]

I do not have overlapping geometry.I have tried higher sample counts and de-noising.

Comment: It is hard to tell what could be the issue just by looking at the picture. If possible please share an example .blend file for testing. If not possible - try giving the character a standard material. If the glitch is gone share the material you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the sun. Turning shadows from the sun off made no noticeable difference in my scene but fixed this issue.